# C++ template specialization and function returned value

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

How would I specialize the getValue() function in the following example to return a value based on a type? How to achieve this in the class definition? Is it possible?

```
template <typename Type>
class Abc
{
    public:
        Type init;
        Abc() : init(getValue()) {}
    private:
        template<> static uint8_t getValue() { return 123; }
        template<> static uint16_t getValue() { return 45678; }
};
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: sure, but it is outside the class definition. Would the same be possible inside?

Comment: Could you add show a small `main` function that uses `Abc` and describe the behavior you want?

Comment: @noonespecial that's thing about template members  of template or nested templates.. you still will be required to specialize them outside (some compilers break that rule, e.g. some versions of Miscrosoft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to write a non-templated function that returns a value depending on the template parameter of the class:

```
template <typename Type>
class Abc
{
    ...
    static Type getValue() { 
        if (std::is_same<Type, std::uint8_t>::value) {
            return 123;
        } else if (std::is_same<Type, std::uint16_t>::value) {
            return 45678;
        }
    }
};
```

This example is simple enough that this will compile with C++11: both `return` statements are valid regardless of whether `Type` is a `uint8_t` or a `uint16_t`. However, if it gets more complicated you might have to use C++17's [`constexpr if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), for example:

```
    static Type getValue() { 
        if constexpr (std::is_same<Type, std::uint8_t>::value) {
            return 123;
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same<Type, std::uint16_t>::value) {
            return 45678;
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same<Type, const char *>::value) {
            return "9abcdef";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The constexpr-if solved this and another of issues I had. Thanks a lot!